# Why did Naruto cut his hair?

Tags: naruto

Naruto cut his hair first in *The Last: Naruto the Movie* and kept it.

Does it have sentimental value, or does he just not want to look like his dad?

Comment: i think the hair cut is just for new and mature look for naruto, i don't think it has any other meaning.

Answer (score 4):

He is now the Hokage and the father of two children. I think the designer wanted to give Naruto a mature old look with all of his responsibilities and stuff.

Also don't forget that there is a main character (the new main character), **Boruto**, which looks like exactly like old Naruto.

But the new look has removed the mischief smile I loved about him.